# cron + evolution data server + msync returning libebook-WARNING

Tags: bash, cron

Ok, i got a working synchronisation between mobile and evolution using opensync and the lib-evo2 module.

issueing

```
msynctool --sync w880i --filter-objtype note --filter-objtype event --filter-objtype todo --conflict n
```

directly works fine, in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
msynctool --sync w880i --filter-objtype note --filter-objtype event --filter-objtype todo --conflict n
exit 0
```

it does aswell.

But putting it in a crontab, this error pops up:

```
(process:18902): libebook-WARNING **: e_book_construct: Could not obtain a handle to the Personal Addressbook Server with IID `OAFIID:GNOME_Evolution_Exchange_Connector_BookFactory:1.2'
```

how do i solve this?

[edit]my crontab entry looks something like this:

```
@daily /usr/local/bin/w880i-sync.sh
```

with being the script mentioned earlier. [/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a problem of missing environment variables. When started with cron, you won't have the same environment as if you log in.

From the man page of crontab (5):

> Environment variables can be set in the crontab.  In BSD  or  ATT,  the
>          environment  handed  to  child  processes  is  basically  the  one from
>          /etc/rc.

So, check your environment and add needed settings into your script.

Answer (score 0):

In a script to be run by `cron` it's always a good idea to include the full path to any executables (i.e. `dbus-launch` and `msynctool`).